How to display a user's mouse pointer position in Google Documents?
There's a feature in Google Slides that shows collaborator's pointer positions in real time. There's no feature like this on Google Documents.
Using Google Apps Script, how would I be able to get a user's pointer position on the document to display it to other users or insert something in that place to indicate it's position without interfering with the rest of the document? Ideally it would work very similarly to the Google Slides version, but I'd settle for something simpler if needed.
Searching Google for answers just pulls up videos and questions about the Google Slides version, and I can't find anything relating towards Google Docs or Google Apps Script being able to do this.
Example:

* Image of pointer from Google Slides

This is impossible in Google Docs using Google Apps Script because the Documents Service (Class DocumentApp) and the Advanced Document Service (Google Docs API) don't include methods to get the mouse pointer position.
You might create a feature request, but you should be patient in the Google Apps Script Issue tracker. For details, see How to get help.
In the meantime, one option might be to create a web browser extension to be installed by each of the document editors. I'm sorry, but I can't provide details on this now.
